# How to calculate remaining quantities of each unit of Items in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, database

I need to allow the client to sell using multiple units.
For Example:

I bought 5 Boxes, each box has 15 Packet, each Packet has 9 Carton of Milk.

When I sell 2 Boxes, 3 Packets and 7 Carton of Milk.
I want to calculate the remaining quantity of each unit to be like:

Remaining 2 Boxes, 11 Packet and 2 Cartons.

I have these tables and Data:
here is the tables and data:

```
Bills Table:
ID | Type | Cus_Sup_ID | Discount | Paid | Notes
1 | Purchase | 1 | 0 | 700 | No Notes
2 | Sale | 2 | 0 | 700 | No Notes

ItemsBills:
ID | ItemID | Unit | Quantity | Price | BillID
1 | 1 | Box | 7 | 100 | 1
2 | 1 | Box | 2 | 100 | 2
3 | 1 | Packet | 5 | 30 | 2
4 | 1 | Carton | 4 | 10 | 2

ItemsUnits:
BigUnit | Has | SmallUnit
Packet | 9 | Carton
Box | 15 | Packet
```

in ItemsBills Table I bought 7 Boxes of Milk, in ItemsUnits Table shows that each Box has 15 Packet and each Packet has 9 Carton of Milk.
in Bill No2 I sold 2 Boxes, 5 Packets and 4 Cartons of Milk.
I want to calculate the remaining quantitiy of each unit from ItemsBills Table to be shown as:
Remaining 4 Boxes, 3 Packets and 5 Cartons.

Comment: this is the classical application for the concept of transactions. you would have a second table to log the transactions, and probably a primary key/foreign key relation based on integer numbers? the definition of how many x contain how many y would be best kept in a rules table joined to the article masterdata table.

Comment: I have this table too:
ItemID | Quanitity | Unit | Price | BillID

if the bill is buy the quantity will positive (+), if the bill is sale bill the quantity will be negative (-)

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: Since you are going in a app development context put all calculation on the Business Logic layer and just use the DB to persist data

Comment: Please instead of putting hard to read stuff and increasing the comments edit your question

Comment: Ok, THanks Mr @jean :)

Comment: This look like a programing exercise. If you change your model to something like a Coin value you can use a basic Money Change Back Calculator algorithm to calculate from one "collection size" to another, so it's just a matter of always calculating to and from unitary values

Comment: Yes Mr. @jean, but what is the code or algorithm to calculate that?